# Azure AD B2C domain cookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, azure-ad-b2c, owin.security

I have a web app which runs under service.domain.de. For authentication in this app I use Azure AD B2C. In the azure security cookie is for the domain service.domain.de . What can I do to get the security cookie for the domain .domain.de? So with the domain .domain.de the cookie is for the domain.de and all subdomains.
The service I wrote in ASP.Net and used Microsoft.Owin.Security library (OpenId).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add CookieAuthentication, you can control the domain via CookieAuthenticationOptions' [CookieDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.owin.security.cookies.cookieauthenticationoptions.cookiedomain(v=vs.113).aspx#P:Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.CookieAuthenticationOptions.CookieDomain) like so:

```cs
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
  CookieDomain = "domain.de"
});
```

Comment: When I use it. It runs without any errors. But when I return to the my service, after authentication in Azure AD B2C, there is no cookie set.
It only works fine wenn I

'    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions {
       CookieDomain = "service.domain.de"
    });'

Comment: Did you test this with the deployed site or just with localhost. It will only work in the deployed site provided that it's in that domain or a subdomain of it.

Comment: It test it with the deployed site under service.domain.de . When I write CookieDmain = "service.domain.de" it runs fine. By CookieDmain = "domain.de" or CookieDmain = ".domain.de" the cookie will not create.